# Register/unregister other application from Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) by my application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android application and want to register/unregister other third party applications from GCM using my application.

I know that i can register/unregister my application from GCM, but haven't found anything on interacting with other applications for the purpose defined above.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unregister other applications from GCM using your app.

Applications register with the device id + application id provided by Google which is kept as secret. Unless you own the applications, there's no way for you to unregister them.